# Global variable increment but when I try to decrement it doesn't work

Tags: c

I have a program that communicate trough a TCP socket, with a server and a client.

Besides other things I have a buffer with pendent requests from the client, and I have also one thread that prints the requests that are being placed in the buffer by the main-thread.

So, for example, I have 3 requests for print 3 files, and the printer_thread have to print the  3 files one after the other. For doing this, I have a function "get", that get the the file to print and a function "put" that put the files in the buffer. When I do the get of something of the buffer it works pretty well and the printing of the file works too.

The problem arises when the client want to know how many files are in the buffer to be printed. I need to have a counter that any time that a put a thing in the buffer it increment, and any time that I get something it decrement, something easy.

But it doesn't work, my program only increment the variable and doesn't make any decrement.

```
int count = 0;
struct prodcons buffer;

/* some other code that is not important for now and works well */

void main_thread(int port_number){

/* more code */

put(&buffer, f_open);
count++;   ------> it increment every time that I do a put
nw = myWriteSocket(sc, "File has been Queued.", ARGVMAX);

/* more code */

void *printing(void *arg){

/* variables and other code that works */

file_desc = get(&buffer);
count--;  ---> now it never decrement, but the get is working because the files are printed


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

/* more code */

pthread_create(&printer_thread,NULL,printing, (void *)terminal);
    main_thread(port_number);
```

What can be the problem? Why the get is working and all is working too and the count-- doesn't???

Sorry if the question is not well structured.

Comment: unless you post compilable code that demonstrates the behavior I doubt someone can solve your issue. I hope you realize a statement like `global variables don't work in C` is ridiculous

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a local variable `count` declared in `printing`?  If you did, that variable would be updated in preference to your global.

Comment: @simonc - I suspect exactly the same thing. Suggest OP change the name of `count` in the variable declaration, and just the two statements that are shown here - then see if the problem goes away. Either that, or search for all instances of `count`.

Comment: It's working now, I had "count = 0" inside main_thread(), sorry for spend your time with this thing....